# Trouble with NSDateFormatter with Timezone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I need to get a date from a string:

```
13:00:00-05
```

I have tried:

```
NSString *dateString = @"13:00:00-05";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ssX"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ssXX"];

DLog(@"date: %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);
```

Both result:

```
date: 2000-01-01 18:00:00 +0000
```

Format:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ssZ"];
```

result:

```
date: 2000-01-01 18:00:00 +0000
```

Format:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss-z"];
```

result:

```
date: 2000-01-01 12:59:59 +0000
```

Format:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss-x"];
```

result:

```
date: (null)
```

but I can't not figure out the format for the UTC offset.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The output for `X` and `XX` is correct. `13:00` in the timezone `-05` is `18:00` in the UTC timezone.

Comment: Er... I don't want it to adjust like that, how can I keep the UTC timezone seperate?

Comment: It is. What you are seeing is simply the result of logging the `NSDate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is the proper format for a timezone in the format `-05`.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ssx"];
```

Comment: But that's the correct result. 13:00 in the -5 timezone is `18:00` in the UTC timezone`.

Comment: Oh, my mistake.  I was assuming the UTC timezone would be keep separate and not change the actual hour.

Comment: The hour isn't changing. It's simply a display thing.

Comment: I think you are right. When I convert string to date, then date to string I get | testDate: 12:00:00-06.  But how can I maintain the original time zone? Or is that something I should no be concerned about since 12h in zone 6 is the same as 13h in zone 5?

Comment: `NSDate` is simply a point in time. Only worry about timezone when you want to display the time to the user.